Is this the only way to get DaisyUI colors based on the theme in Svelte?
I'm using Svelte with DaisyUI and need to retrieve the current theme colors dynamically. I rely on these colors in chroma-js, so it’s crucial to get them correctly. The code below works for me, but it feels like there might be a more efficient or idiomatic way to achieve this. Is this the only/best approach to get the current theme colors from DaisyUI?
Here’s the relevant code snippet:
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { theme } from '$stores/global';
    import type { ThemeColor, ThemeColorMap } from "$type/shared";

    type ColorElement = {
        [key in ThemeColor]?: HTMLDivElement | undefined;
    };

    export let colors: ThemeColorMap;

    const colorKeys: ThemeColor[] = ['accent', 'info', 'neutral'];
    let colorElements: ColorElement = {} as ColorElement; // This will store references to the div elements

    function getColors(): ThemeColorMap {
        if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
            return {};
        }

        let newColors: ThemeColorMap = {};
        Object.entries(colorElements).forEach(([key, element]) => {
            if (element) {
                newColors[key as ThemeColor] = getComputedStyle(element).backgroundColor;
            }
        });
        return newColors;
    }

    onMount(() => {
        colors = getColors();
    });

    theme.subscribe(() => {
        colors = getColors();
    });
</script>

<div class="hidden">
    {#each colorKeys as key}
        <div class="bg-{key}" bind:this={colorElements[key]}></div>
    {/each}
</div>

This approach creates hidden div elements with DaisyUI color classes, and then I use getComputedStyle to extract the background color from these elements.
While this works, it feels a bit hacky, especially with the hidden elements. Is there a more direct or efficient way to access the current DaisyUI theme colors in Svelte, particularly for use with chroma-js?
Any suggestions would be appreciated!
